# Microsoft Dynamics CRM On-Premise SOAP error

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm

I'm making a PHP SOAP request to Microsoft CRM Dynamics. It seems fine except I'm getting the below error and I can't seem to go round it

```
http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/faulturn:uuid:{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx}00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000002018-05-15T06:41:09.824Z2018-05-15T06:46:09.824Zs:Sendera:FailedAuthenticationAccess
is denied.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hod do you make authenticatication before you call your soap request?

Comment: ^ `FailedAuthenticationAccess`

Comment: What do you mean? I'm getting the AuthHeader but the `WhoAmI` request won't run.

Comment: I discovered that the **`WhoAmI`** is failing causing the error. `<s:Body>
 <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
  <request i:type="c:WhoAmIRequest" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts">
   <b:Parameters xmlns:d="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
   <b:RequestId i:nil="true"/>
   <b:RequestName>WhoAmI</b:RequestName>
  </request>
 </Execute>
</s:Body>`